# Set default value of an integer column in SQLite

Tags: database, sqlite

I am creating an SQLite database.

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" 
    + KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
    + KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " 
    + KEY_WORKED + " INTEGER, "
    + KEY_NOTE + " INTEGER);");
```

Is it possible to set the default value of `KEY_NOTE` (which is an integer) for every row created to be `0` (zero)? If so, what should be the correct code?

Answer (score 273, accepted):

Use the SQLite keyword `default`

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" 
    + KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
    + KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
    + KEY_WORKED + " INTEGER, "
    + KEY_NOTE + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0);");
```

This link is useful: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html

Answer (score 12):

A column with default value:

```
CREATE TABLE <TableName>(
...
<ColumnName> <Type> DEFAULT <DefaultValue>
...
)
```

`<DefaultValue>` is a placeholder for a:

- value literal
- `(` expression `)`

Examples:

```
Count INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
LastSeen TEXT DEFAULT (datetime('now'))
```

Answer (score 6):

It happens that I'm just starting to learn coding and I needed something similar as you have just asked in SQLite (*[I´m using [SQLiteStudio] (3.1.1)](https://sqlitestudio.pl/index.rvt)*).

It happens that you must define the column's '**[Constraint](https://sqlite.org/syntax/column-constraint.html)**' as '**Not Null**' then entering your desired definition using '**Default**' '**[Constraint](https://sqlite.org/syntax/column-constraint.html)**' or it will not work (*I don't know if this is an SQLite or the program requirment*).

Here is the code I used:

```
CREATE TABLE <MY_TABLE> (
<MY_TABLE_KEY>       INTEGER    UNIQUE
                                PRIMARY KEY,
<MY_TABLE_SERIAL>    TEXT       DEFAULT (<MY_VALUE>) 
                                NOT NULL
<THE_REST_COLUMNS>
);
```

Comment: It's the same logic used in MySQL; the default of a nullable column is already NULL, so to set a default otherwise would imply the column is non-nullable. If you specify a default on a nullable column without declaring it NOT NULL, it may confuse you when default NULL values are inserted.

Comment: The UNIQUE statement is not needed and already implied by the PRIMARY KEY statement.

Comment: @dani I agree with you, but it was the only way to bypass the errors that  SQLiteStudio 3.1.1 was generating from lacking of "Unique" condition