# Null and Empty String/Character in SQLIte Android

Tags: android, sqlite

when i execute:
`dbObj.execSql("INSERT INTO table_name (col1,col2) VALUES(1,\"\") ");`
col2 is saved as NULL? or EMPTY STRING? OR WHAT!!!!!?

Because on retrieval it shows col2 is NULL, even when my table_name deifinition is:

`CREATE TABLE table_name(
 col1 INTEGER,
 col2 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT \"\")`;

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17617610/set-default-value-of-an-integer-column-sqlite

Comment: Side note: The SQL string delimeter is `'`, not `"`. sqlite is [quite lenient](https://sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) in this regard, but using `"` in place of `'` is explicitly deprecated.

Comment: what are you trying to store in col2 exactly?

Comment: Show the code that retrieves the value.

Answer (score 1):

No reason to scream. Your question is a little stupid. You insert an empty string. So obviously an empty string is saved.

SQLiteDatabase's method is "execSQL". "execSql" doesn't exist.

Maybe your code to read col2 is wrong...